# error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I'm getting the following error when i tried to decrypt a list of ogg files but when i try to decrypt only one it works this is my code.

```
  for (IpstoriResponse ipstori: descargas) {
                        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
                            ipstori.setAudioHistory(getOfflineFile(ipstori.getAudioPath(), ipstori.getAudioCle(), ipstori.getAudioIv(), requireContext(), ipstori.getAudioCle()));
                            prepareList.add(...);
                        });
                    }
            }

  private String getOfflineFile(String input, String key, String iv, Context context, String name){
    String result = null;
    try {
        File initialFile = new File(input);
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        File outputDir = context.getCacheDir(); // context being the Activity pointer
        File outputFile = File.createTempFile(name, ".ogg", outputDir);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKey secretKey = makeKey(key);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = makeIv(iv);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int nread;
        while ((nread = cipherInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, nread);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        cipherInputStream.close();
        result = outputFile.getPath();
        tempFiles.add(result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ...
    }

    return result;
}
```

that's really weird cause when you try to decrypt only one element of the list the code works fine

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? Could you share your solution?